# dropwizard multiple filter invoked order

Tags: java, dropwizard

When dropwizard adds multiple filters, like the below code:

```
public void initialize(Bootstrap<XxxApiServerConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    ...
    bootstrap.addBundle(new XxxBundle("Xxx"));
    ...

}

public void run(XxxApiServerConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    ...

    Dynamic filter = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);
    filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
    ...

    environment.servlets().addFilter("XxxFilter", XxxFilter.class)
    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/v1/xxx/*");

     ...
```

}

XxxBundle include a Resource Filter,

how to adjust XxxBundle filter and XxxFilter invoked order?

Comment: Looking into the code a little bit, I believe the execution order is Bundle, and then whatever you add. This is because, internally the filters are just added to an array. And the array is simply newArray = oldArray + newFilter. And initialize runs before the run method. However this is really just a 10 second step through code. Why don't you use jersey with your setup? You can annotate your filter and explicitly set execution order there.